# Cannot read property 'symbol' and 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, .net-5

I am developing an API with net 5 and angular 11. In my project I have table StockTransaction which includes stockid from table Stock as a foreign key. I am trying to achieve that when I press BuyStock button, I buy that specific stock. I am indeed able to do so, but I get the message in console - Cannot read property 'symbol' and 'id' of undefined. Basically, I tried to apply the same logic as in standard net application and it is working, but the console is a problem. Here is my code, please let me know if I should put some more code, I did not want this to be to long question. Thanks in advance!

**stockservice**

```
buyStock() {
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrlTup}/${this.formData.stockId}`, this.formData);
}
```

**add-stock.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-add-stock',
templateUrl: './add-stock.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-stock.component.scss']
})
export class AddStockComponent implements OnInit {
stock: IStock;


constructor(public stocksService: StocksService,
          private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          private bcService: BreadcrumbService,
          private transactionService: TransactionsService,
          private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.loadStock();
this.stocksService.formData.stockId = this.stock.id;
}

 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
 this.stocksService.formData.stockId = this.stock.id;
 this.buyingStock(form);
}

 loadStock() {
 return 
 this.stocksService.getStock(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(response => 
{
  this.stock = response;
  this.bcService.set('@stockDetails', this.stock.companyName);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}

 buyingStock(form: NgForm) {
 this.stocksService.buyStock().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.resetForm(form);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('myportfolio');
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
 );
 }

resetForm(form: NgForm) {
form.form.reset();
this.transactionService.formData = new IStTransaction();
}
}
```

**add-stock.component.html**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
<div class="col-5">
   
    <form novalidate autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm" 
(submit)="onSubmit(form)">    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Stock</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder=" 
 {{stock.symbol}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Price" 
name="price"
            #price="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="stocksService.formData.price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" 
placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"
            #quantity="ngModel" 
[(ngModel)]="stocksService.formData.quantity">
        </div>
       <!--  <div class="form-group">
            <label>Resolved</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" 
placeholder="Resolved" name="resolved"
            #resolved="ngModel" 
[(ngModel)]="stocksService.formData.resolved">
        </div> -->
            <div class="meki form-group">
                <button class="zeki btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block mt-3" 
 type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
             
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: pls show html also

Comment: Also, plz share the code where you use the property "symbol"

Comment: <div class="text-center">
                <button routerLink="/stocks/{{stock.id}}" mdbBtn size="sm" mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="m-0 btn btn-info mr-5">Details</button>
                <button routerLink="/stocks/addstock/{{stock.id}}" mdbBtn size="sm" mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="mr-5 btn btn-success">Add Stock</button>
                <button routerLink="/stocks/addstockReactive/{{stock.id}}" mdbBtn size="sm" mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="m-0 btn btn-success">Add Stock Reactive</button>

              </div>

Comment: sorry trying to do that, am new to stackowerflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you use `stock` and its members before the data arrived from response. Try to use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html).

Example :

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="{{stock?.symbol}}">
```

Comment: not really sure what you mean, what should I do?

Comment: use ```stock``` object with optional chaining. I appended the code.

Comment: thanks, it helped!...but now I get -cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Use this also in ```ngOnInit``` :)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: click on pipe next to my answer.

Comment: I pressed - this answer is useful - is that enough?

Comment: I recommend you this : https://stackoverflow.com/tour